# NSPredicate with condition based on recursive relationship - Swift - Core Data

Tags: swift, recursion, core-data, nspredicate, recursive-query

I am using Core Data and I have a basic folder structure represented. Each item (file/folder) is a row in the table. Each item has a `name` property and also an optional relationship which points to the item which is its parent. I am trying to write a function which takes in an array of strings representing a path (e.g. `["myFolder", "mySubfolder", "mySubSubfolder", "myFile"]`) and returns the item which is found at that path. In English, what I would like to ask Core Data is "give me all items whose name is `myFile`, whose parent's name is `mySubSubfolder`, whose grandparent's name is `mySubfolder`, and whose great grandparent's name is `myFolder`". The much easier way to describe this in words is to define a condition called `item(at: path)` which says to Core Data "give me all items whose name is `path.last` and whose parent satisfies `item(at: path.dropLast())`". I have hope in my heart that there is a fancy feature of predicates which makes this possible, but I am new enough to them that I am having trouble googling my way to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use strongly-typed methods where possible instead of constructing and parsing format strings at runtime.

```
import Foundation

func predicateMatchingPath(_ path: [String]) -> NSPredicate {
    var path = path
    guard let last = path.popLast() else {
        return NSPredicate(value: false)
    }

    var ancestorKeyPath = ""
    let nameSuffix = "name"
    var predicates = [NSPredicate]()

    predicates.append(NSComparisonPredicate(
        leftExpression: NSExpression(forKeyPath: ancestorKeyPath + nameSuffix),
        rightExpression: NSExpression(forConstantValue: last),
        modifier: .direct, type: .equalTo, options: []))

    while let anscestor = path.popLast() {
        ancestorKeyPath.append("parent.")
        predicates.append(NSComparisonPredicate(
            leftExpression: NSExpression(forKeyPath: ancestorKeyPath + nameSuffix),
            rightExpression: NSExpression(forConstantValue: anscestor),
            modifier: .direct, type: .equalTo, options: []))
    }

    // Make sure the most distant ancestor is a root.
    predicates.append(NSComparisonPredicate(
        leftExpression: NSExpression(forKeyPath: ancestorKeyPath + "parent"),
        rightExpression: NSExpression(forConstantValue: nil),
        modifier: .direct, type: .equalTo, options: []))

    return NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
}

print(predicateMatchingPath(["myFolder", "mySubfolder", "mySubSubfolder", "myFile"]))

// Output:
name == "myFile" AND parent.name == "mySubSubfolder" AND parent.parent.name == "mySubfolder" AND parent.parent.parent.name == "myFolder" AND parent.parent.parent.parent == nil
```

Comment: I understand the benefits of utilizing the type system, but in this case the massive amount of extra code doesn't seem worth it. Are there tangible benefits to your method?

Answer (score 0):

Ok actually I think I figured it out. Haven't actually tested it yet but conceptually it seems right. Here is the code which creates the proper predicate string:

```
var predicateString = ""
var i = 0
for pathComponent in path.reversed() {
    predicateString += "name == \(pathComponent) && parent"
    for _ in 0 ..< i {
        predicateString += ".parent"
    }
    i += 1
    guard i != path.count else { continue }
    predicateString += "."
}
predicateString += " == nil"
```